# InitializeEnvironment Postman script always returned the status as "WaitingForActivation"

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

Whenever i tried to trigger `InitializeEnvironment` Postman script..

```
{{OpsApiHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/InitializeEnvironment(environment='{{Environment}}')
```

I always get below as a response.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5000/CommerceOps/$metadata#Commands/$entity",
    "Id": "7d681424004f4c80850d0c4e19352eeb",
    "ResponseCode": "Ok",
    "Messages": [],
    "Models": [],
    "ActionUrl": "",
    "TaskId": 446547,
    "Status": "WaitingForActivation",
    "IsFaulted": false,
    "IsCompleted": false,
    "IsCanceled": false
}
```

And i think, that is the reason why my environment is not properly initialized.

Update 1: Added logs

> 18 19:31:09 INFO Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET
>   http://localhost:5000/commerceops/InitializeEnvironment(environment='ArvindAuthoring')
>   18 19:31:09 INFO Successfully validated the token. 18 19:31:09 INFO
>   AuthenticationScheme: "BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt" was
>   successfully authenticated. 18 19:31:09 INFO AuthenticationScheme:
>   "Bearer" was successfully authenticated. 18 19:31:09 INFO
>   Authorization was successful for user: "sitecore\Admin". 13 19:31:09
>   INFO Executing action method
>   "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.CommandsController.InitializeEnvironment
>   (Sitecore.Commerce.Core)" with arguments (["ArvindAuthoring"]) -
>   ModelState is Valid 13 19:31:09 INFO Executing ObjectResult, writing
>   value "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext". 13 19:31:09 INFO
>   Executed action
>   "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.CommandsController.InitializeEnvironment
>   (Sitecore.Commerce.Core)" in 13.4489ms 13 19:31:09 INFO Request
>   finished in 33.8218ms 200 application/json; odata.metadata=minimal;
>   odata.streaming=true; charset=utf-8 28 19:31:09 INFO
>   Management.block.ValidateSitecoreConnection: Validating Sitecore
>   connection: Url=https://storefront.local, Environment=ArvindAuthoring.
>   28 19:31:09 INFO SQL:blocks:ValidateSqlConnection: Validating Entity
>   Store SQL connection: Environment=ArvindAuthoring 13 19:31:10 INFO
>   Pricing.block.InitializeEnvironmentDefaultPriceBookBlock.InitializingArtifactSet:
>   ArtifactSet=Pricing.DefaultPriceBook-1.0 28 19:31:10 WARN
>   CtxMsg.ValidationError.BookNameAlreadyInUse: Text=Book name
>   DefaultPriceBook is already in
>   use.|Shopper=|Shop=|Correlation=924d5a55e5e747ada5bcac7ebdcd4d7c 26
>   19:31:10 INFO Management.GetCommerceTerms./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce
>   Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/System
>   Messages|en 13 19:31:10 INFO
>   Management.block.getitemsbypath./sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control
>   Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/System Messages|en 13
>   19:31:13 ERROR PipelineAbort:Book name DefaultPriceBook is already in
>   use. 13 19:31:13 ERROR
>   Pricing.block.InitializeEnvironmentDefaultPriceBookBlock.Error:
>   Message=The price book can not be null.

Any clue?

Comment: can you add to your question logs from engine server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the CleanEnvironment command first. You cannot run the InitializeEnvironment twice without running the CleanEnvironment command, because it will try to import the same entities.

Answer (score 1):

InitializeEnvironment is a long operation. As you can see in the response IsCompleted is false. In the commerce Postman collection, you can find the request "Check Long Running Command Status" which you can execute to check the InitializeEnvironment status.